# django include a template into another template

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I am trying to include a template into another template but the problem I am having now is the embedded templates doesnt display contents rendered on it in the new template I am trying to embed it into.

**detail.html in profile application**

```
{% include "list.html" with instance=user.posts_created.all %}
```

and I have the template in the templates folder. The template is seen but the content does not show up in the detail.html

additional codes would be provided on request thanks

**views.py in posts app**

```
def axle(request , tag_slug=None):
    results = Post.objects.all().filter(draft=False)#.filter(publish__lte=timezone.now())
    #results = results.filter(user=request.user)
    tag = None
    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        results = results.filter(tags__in=[tag])
    que = request.GET.get("q")
    if que:
        results =results.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=que)|
            Q(content__icontains=que)).distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(results, 4) # Show 25 contacts per page
    pages ="page"
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        query = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        query = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        query = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "objects": query,
        "pages": pages
    }
    template = 'list.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
```

Comment: did you have only one `list.html`, can you show the source of it

Comment: yes I have only one

Comment: can you show it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have something like this in your `view`:

```
def post(request):
    post_list = posts_created.objects.all() # or something which you want to do.
    context = {
    'post_list': post_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

In `template`:

```
{% include "app_name/list.html" with objects=post_list %}
```

Comment: list.html is in another app

Comment: make sure that `list.html` is accessible, you might need to use `app_name/list.html`, check your template structure and you'll get an idea how to use it in another app.

Comment: @King add your `list.html`, or make sure which variable you passed in `list.html`, make sure to use same here. Like if you have `{% for object in object_list %}` in your `list.html`, use `{% include "app_name/list.html" with object_list=post_list %}`. Use accordingly what you used in `list.html`, use same in `detail.html`.

Comment: list.html accessible

Comment: what `key` you are accessing in `list.html` from its corresponding `view`. If it is `instance`, then its OK, else use it in `detail.html` same what you passed in `list.html`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152761/discussion-between-piyush-maurya-and-king).